# "Unrecognized escape sequence" errors in hello world program (AssemblyInfo.cs)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just created a Hello World to test this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Helloworld1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same errors no matter what I build:

```
Error   1   Newline in constant AssemblyInfo.cs 11  28  Helloworld1
Error   2   Unrecognized escape sequence AssemblyInfo.cs    13  46  Helloworld1
Error   3   Syntax error, ']' expected  AssemblyInfo.cs 36  43  Helloworld1
Error   4   ) expected AssemblyInfo.cs  36  43  Helloworld1
```

Note the line numbers.  There aren't 36 lines in this code!
Can somebody tell me what is going on.  (And, yes, I have closed and reopened my Visual Studio 2010 Pro.)

Comment: The error claims to be coming from your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.  Show that.

Comment: can you please show us the code of `AssemblyInfo.cs` class

Comment: This is only easily explained by a corrupted hard drive.  Feel free to panic.  Do *not* wildly delete files to solve the problem, use another machine to go to superuser.com to ask for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you edit the Assembly properties (*Project Properties->Assembly Information*) and enter an invalid character such as a backslash (`\`) into any of the fields like Description, etc.

You get an error as though it didn't save, but it does - and this then causes a problem when you try to compile.

Just open AssemblyInfo.cs in the Properties fodler and VS will red-sguiggle the offending character, remove it and if the red lines go away, you're good to go.

[image: Example of the problem as it looks in the IDE]

Comment: Thanks! Great answer Stephen. This was affecting all my programs. Unfortunately, I haven't played with any properties yet, so not sure what caused this. I am just learning C# and have only been loading in the program window. Again, thanks!

Comment: Cool. I wonder if it isn't maybe some addon or extension that tried to do something clever with the assembly info when you created a new project?

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra file included in every Visual Studio project, in the Properties folder, called AssemblyInfo.cs. Open that and you'll find that something's not quite right.

If you're not sure, you can just delete it - it's not required for your project to run, although it can be useful.

Comment: While you are correct, I wouldn't encourage deleting but rather fixing the problem.

Comment: @TimMedora true - just hoping to get someone off the mark as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

I always get compiling errors from AssemblyInfo.cs file when creating a new project in VS2012. The problem always seems to be a line break.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("
            ")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Html5Testing")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 
             2014")]
```

I manually remove the line break and issue is solved.

I also googled for this and, surprisingly, I couldn't find too many people facing it. This makes me think that it could be a setting on my local version of VS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the AssemblyInfo.cs file - it's in Properties folder. The error is there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your registry keys at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization
```

and make sure that it either has your org name or is blank.

I had a similar problem, every time I would start a new project I had newlines in my assembly.cs file that I had to go remove. In that reg key I found that I had a long string of whitespace.